# Notaped++: pasting in block edit mode in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

I can enter the block edit mode using Shift+Alt+A in Eclipse. For Notepad++ [they recommend](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/feature-requests/14/#bdb6)

> push down the Alt key then select the block you want with the mouse
>   (without releasing the Alt key).

This way I can copy a block indeed. But how do I paste the clipboarded block? What the hell?

Comment: Ctrl V as per normal?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot paste in block mode unless your text was copied in Notepad++ also in block mode. You cannot simply copy it from another app and paste as per block mode. Paste your text in Notepad++ first, then copy it using Alt+mouse and paste again. This time, it will be pasted as the block, at desired location.